# Updating another cell value on a cell value change in WPF Datagrid

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, wpfdatagrid

If I edit a cell value in my WPF datagrid I want to change another cell value dynamically in the same row in the datagrid . I am using  celleditending event of the cell currently. What is the best way to do it

Answer (score 0):

The best way is having the underlying model implementing `INotifyPropertyChange`, modify the value in the model when the property connected to your 'master' cell changes,  and fire the event accordingly.

Comment: But I want to update the value in my cellEndEditing event. Can I do it there